# Dynamically create a regex pattern from input string

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, regex, string

I have multiple strings stored in my database called order number pattern. This pattern is dictated by the master user/company when setting up the application for themselves.

Therefore any user that creates an order from their company has to follow this pattern. The pattern set could be anything like `'000000'` or `'AAA00000'` or `'AA00aaa000'` and so on (mixture of numbers, upper case letters, lower case letters and special characters)

What I need to do is to validate that when an user enters the order number, it matches the pattern set by the company i.e. if the user enters `BX12-xyz-345` then check that it matches pattern `'AA00-aaa-000'`.

What I thought would be ideal is to generate a regex pattern based on the current pattern and store that against the customer record therefore it makes it easier for me to then match using `Regex.match` function. The only problem with this is that I have to manually create the regex patterns for each of our approx 250+ customers and therefore was wondering if there is way where I can pass in a string and it returns me a regex pattern for that string.

Ideally if I could do this in `SQL server (vial bulk update)` if not I do not mind creating a one time exe in `C#` that can go and update each record with its regex pattern and also change the application such that in future it only stores the regex pattern in the database.

Comment: I fear the answer is you could probably write one to sit there and pattern match and decide that this one has 3 letters, followed by 6 numbers, and that one is 2 letters 8 numbers 2 letters.. but.. it would be quicker to type in the 250 codes.

Comment: The problem is that when we then have a new customer and they enter a pattern of say AA-0000-aaa then i have remember to go and update the regex for that record and if I forget then system would then not function properly

Comment: Agreed. There are tools out there to assist with figuring out possible patterns, but it's very difficult to be certain you found the correct pattern. In your example, if a user enters BX12-xyz-345, how do you know the opattern isn't AX##-aaa-###? Or if any of those fields may be alphanumeric?

You're *much* better off requiring a pattern to be provided by the customer during the requirements gathering/onboarding phase.

If you're having a problem remembering to do stuff, look into process tooling. If you forget to do something like this, you're probably missing other things too.

Comment: Why dynamic? If there's only the things you've outlines here you can use one regex. `^\d{6}$|^[A-Z]{3}-?\d{5}$|^[A-Z]{2}-?\d{2}-?[a-z]{3}-?\d{3}$`  This specific regex would check that the code is in the format `000000`, `AAA-00000`, `AAA00000`, `AA00aaa000` or even `AA-00-aaa-000` or `AA00-aaa-000`, etc.

Comment: Since REGEX is extremely limited in SQL Server, this would be the last place I would try to handle it. e.g., don't do the check in SQL. Just my two cents.

Comment: It depends on how rigid the patterns are.  From what you've shown so far it seems as simple as replacing "A" with [A-Z], "a" with [a-z], and "0" with [0-9], but I'm guessing the patterns maybe more complex than that.

Comment: No the pattern could be any mixture of upper case, lower case letters and numbers with a '-' as a special character if they want to use it.

Comment: @CodeNinja well in that case maybe you should add some structuring to your codes to avoid this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming A/a/0 represent A-Z, a-z and 0-9 & you don't use any reserved pattern characters you can build a pattern mask:

```
declare @pattern varchar(max) = 'AA00-aaa-000'

set @pattern = replace(replace(replace(@pattern COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN, 'A', '[A-Z]'), 'a', '[a-z]'), '0', '[0-9]')

select @pattern
```

> [A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9]-[a-z][a-z][a-z]-[0-9][0-9][0-9]

```
if 'BX12-xyz-345' like @pattern print 'y'
```